# Using partialy initialized object in tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a concern regarding usage of "improperly" initialized objects in unit tests.
Let's say I want to tests a function:

```
void foo(SomeClass)
{
 //do some stuff based on SomeClass.value
}
```

where:

```
class SomeClass 
{
OtherClass* ptr;
int uninterestingValue;
int value;
};
```

What I want to do is create function (available only in unit test, namely in anonymous namespace) which:

```
SomeClass createDummy()
{
SomeClass dummy(nullptr, 0, //initialize uninteresting fields with nullptr/0
                42)         //42 will be used for testing purpose
}
```

*Reason:* creating object of SomeClass type is complex, as it is used to represent final state of data processing in system. I'd like to simplify it a bit.

Would it be considered a bad approach?

Are there better ways to achieve this (talking specificly about C++/googletest?

Comment: Is there a way you could reformat  or reword your question so it isnt one long paragraph? Some users might open this to help you and not want to deal with the headache of understanding what you say. I am just trying to help you out. If you want some help take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @B.Cratty Thank you for advice! I hope it's a bit easier to understand it now.

Comment: Have you considered the using mocks? You can try [gmock](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock) or [Isolator++](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Ipp&page=faking_concrete_classes.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three parts to your question. I won't address whether or not there are better ways, but the approach your talking about is not bad.

The idea of using dummy objects with only the important parts implemented is standard. There are several variations on the idea of using test doubles. Test doubles include mocks, fakes, stubs, and spies. Using those terms to search google should give you plenty of information about that idea. Here's an article [that explains the difference](https://blog.pragmatists.com/test-doubles-fakes-mocks-and-stubs-1a7491dfa3da). Since you are using Google Test, you should look into how you can [use the Google Mock extension](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md) to make your test doubles.

The second idea is about having a builder to create the dummy objects. Two relevant patterns are Object Mother and Test Data Builder. You can search those terms or get started with [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/Podwysocki/archive/2008/01/08/118362.aspx).

Comment: While I think that would a bit of "overkill" to implement new class creating such data in this case (which will be used only in this one test case), it may (and will) come in handy in other scenarios. Thank you for advice and interesting reading!